# How to change the characters of a word when hovering over it with the cursor?

Tags: javascript

Example: https://www.dragonfly.xyz
When you hover the cursor over the "MEDIUM" button in the left corner of the screen, an unusual effect runs through the letters.

I don't really understand how to describe this question to Google, I hope you can help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this maybe? https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/

Comment: The answer is that he has custom javascript running that changes the letters on hover. The specifics of that javascript are anyone's guess, but if you learn how to code generally you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: If you want somewhere to start, because you're new to programming, consider Jquery's `element.on('mouseover', ev => {})` as a place to trigger behaviour on hover

Comment: Realistically, as TKoL said, if you want the exact implementation you probably are going to have to implement it yourself and discover what you can do with JS. Otherwise you'll have to stick to whatever is closest to what you want to acheive from what's available for free online.

Comment: good evening! thank you for the time you have given to the question) Now I will try to deal with Jquery

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.jqueryscript.net/plus/search.php?kwtype=0&keyword=shuffle+text A few jQuery examples to shuffle text. The examples I checked don't use mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is too large and general to answer, I'm going to put you in a place to start experimenting yourself.

```js
$('h1').hover(function() {
    $(this).text('test');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: light;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>MEDIUM</h1>
```

I've included jquery in the above snippet and assigned a `.hover` function to the h1 element. At this point, you could trigger some code to iterate over every letter and animate changes. If you want to know how animation over time works, research `Window.requestAnimationFrame`, which is an API available in all browsers.

Comment: @pr0m31h3u5 you might want to use `.on('mouseover'` instead of `.hover`

Comment: @pr0m31h3u5 just for fun, I made this https://jsfiddle.net/jankzb16/